# Resize TEXT to Fit on UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there possible to resize text to fi my UITextView? I tried something like:

```
  if (_myTextView.contentSize.height > _myTextView.frame.size.height)
{
    _myTextView.font = [_myTextView.font fontWithSize:25];
}
```

This resizing text very well, but i have some lines of text which are longer and then i need to decrease my font size.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the same idea iteratively ...

```
CGFloat fontSize = 25.0;
_myTextView.font = [_myTextView.font fontWithSize:fontSize];

while (_myTextView.contentSize.height > _myTextView.frame.size.height && fontSize > 8.0) {
    fontSize -= 1.0;
    _myTextView.font = [_myTextView.font fontWithSize:fontSize];
}
```